# Yum trying to install .el7 release on CentOS 6

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, yum, centos7

I have generated two RPMs. One for CentOS 6 and one for CentOS 7.

`my-package-0.0.1-1.el6.x86_64`

`my-package-0.0.1-1.el7.x86_64`

When I do a `yum info my-package` on a CentOS 6 machine, it gives me the el7 information. When I do `yum install my-package` it does the same, gets the el7 version. Why is it doing this? I'm trying to avoid installing a el7 version on a el6 machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you have them in the same yum repository. You shouldn't. You should be posting one to a CentOS6 repo and the other to a CentOS7 repo. Otherwise, `yum` is comparing them and deciding that 7 > 6 when comparing the release tags, so therefore that's the newest package available.

The `el6` (AKA "dist tag") is a convenience to the user as a suffix to the release, and is *not* something that RPM can select on directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And after consulting with dev ops, they also said the same thing. We've only developed for el6 so I made sure to let them know they need to specify the full Pkg name when installing or to spin up a repo for el7.

Answer (score 4):

Agreeing that apparently OP put both RPMs in the same repository, there are some details overlooked by [@aaron-d-marasco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/836748/aaron-d-marasco):

- the `el6` tag is not a "convenience to the user" but rather a workaround by packagers.
- if you check the meta information for the packages, you may notice that the `.el6` (or `.el7`) in the packages provided are *appended* to the *release* tag, e.g., for `zip-3.0-10.el7.x86_64`, you might see something like this:

  `Name        : zip`
   `Version     : 3.0`
   `Release     : 10.el7`
   `Architecture: x86_64`
- the RPM selection rules use the *whole* tags for *version* and *release* for each *name* specified.
- the *dist* tag mentioned is sorted along with the rest of the *release* tag
- the workaround is because there is no separate meta information for distribution in the schema, but packagers want to keep track of this.
- because the *release* tag is "owned" by the packager (and *version* by the upstream development), then the packagers get to decide how it is used for organizing packages — subject to the built-in rules for RPM selection by [`yum`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/yum.8.html).

Further reading:

- [RPM File Naming Convention](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-rpm-file-format.html)
- [How Yum and RPM Compare Versions](http://blog.jasonantman.com/2014/07/how-yum-and-rpm-compare-versions/)

Comment: Wow how Yum compares rpms and versions is kinda crazy. Thanks for the read. I've also thought that putting the %{dist} tag in the release field was a lil wonky and most likely a work around. Especially when there is dist macros available on the system e.g. {el}, {centos}

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; I've tweaked my answer to include. I had meant that yum/rpm couldn't *directly* select that tag, because it's not a "real" tag in the specfile.